# How to show tooltip for each react-select multiValue element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip, react-select

I'm trying to reproduce the example of the [Custom MultiValueContainer Example](https://react-select.com/components#replaceable-components) shown in the link, but nothing seems to work properly. The element is inserted (can be found within the React Component dev-tool) but the tooltip is never shown when hovered.

The code I'm trying to run is shown [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-react-select-7y4wo?file=/src/App.js), but even the simple code given in the example does not seem to work, as shown [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-14o49)

What I expect is something like the following: [image: Expected output of the link]

Has anyone an idea what essential part I am overlooking?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a `<span>` Element to the CustomMultiValue and changing the Tooltip-library to *material-ui*, solved the problem.

```
const CustomMultiValue = (props) => {
  return (
    <Tooltip title={"Here we could show the legend of the element"}>
      <span>
        <MultiValueContainer {...props} />
      </span>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an individual tooltip per item you may do it like this:

```
const CustomMultiValueLabel = props => {
    return (
        <MultiValueLabel {...props} >
        <div className={styles.tooltip}>
            {props.data.label}
            <span className={styles.tooltiptext}>This is the tooltip text for {props.data.label}</span>
        </div>
        </MultiValueLabel>
    );
};

<Select isMulti
        components={{MultiValueLabel: CustomMultiValueLabel}}
>
```